# syn::ItemFn.to_token_stream hidden/guarded?

Tags: rust, macros

I thought I'd try to write a basic function decorator that logs the input and output of functions as they are called.  I have many functions that have roughly the same signature, and I'd like to log the io of common part.  That is, think of adding a decorator like this

```
#[my_decorator]
foo(<unknown initial args>, final_arg: T) -> R {BODY}
```

would effectively turn `foo` into

```
foo(<unknown initial args>, final_arg: T) -> R {
    let result = {BODY};
    debug!("final_arg is {:?}" final_arg)
    debug!("return value is {:?}" result)
    result
}
```

I spent today searching around for best approaches to this and it appears that the best way would be to define a #[proc_macro_attribute]

I am at the following sanity-checking stub (which the documentation [here](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/struct.ItemFn.html) would suggest is valid)

```
use proc_macro::TokenStream;                                                                                                                                                                                                          
use syn;                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
use syn::ItemFn;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
#[proc_macro_attribute]                                                                                                                                                                                                               
pub fn log_io(_attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {                                                                                                                                                                 
    let item_fn: ItemFn = syn::parse_macro_input!(item);                                                                                                                                                                              
    item_fn.to_token_stream()                                                                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

Which IIUC should be the No-Op decorator.  But the compiler gives

```
error[E0599]: no method named `to_token_stream` found for struct `ItemFn` in the current scope
  --> src/lib.rs:8:13
   |
8  |     item_fn.to_token_stream()
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `ItemFn`
   |
  ::: /Users/arthurtilley/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/quote-1.0.21/src/to_tokens.rs:59:8
   |
59 |     fn to_token_stream(&self) -> TokenStream {
   |        --------------- the method is available for `ItemFn` here
   |
   = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
help: one of the expressions' fields has a method of the same name
   |
8  |     item_fn.sig.to_token_stream()
   |             ++++
help: the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it:
   |
1  | use syn::__private::ToTokens;
   |
```

Adding the suspicious looking `use syn::__private::ToTokens;` the compiler then gives

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:9:5
  |
7 | pub fn log_io(_attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
  |                                                         ----------- expected `proc_macro::TokenStream` because of return type
8 |     let item_fn: ItemFn = syn::parse_macro_input!(item);
9 |     item_fn.to_token_stream()
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `proc_macro::TokenStream`, found struct `TokenStream2`
```

None of this is mentioned in the documentation https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/struct.ItemFn.html so I'm a little stumped.

EDIT:  @Shelvacu I'm using

```
syn = {version ="*" ("1.0.99"), features = ["full", "printing", "extra-traits"]}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
proc-macro2 = "*"  ("1.0.43")
```

Comment: Could you post what version of `syn` and `proc_macro` you're using?

Comment: Can you try `item_fn.to_token_stream().into()`? (`.to_token_stream()` returns `proc_macro2::TokenStream` while the function should return `proc_macro::TokenStream`)

Comment: @Dogbert *sigh* yes that does work.  Could you humor me and tell me how I would have figured that out from the docs?  The signature in the docs for ItemFn give `to_token_stream(&self) -> TokenStream`

Answer (score 2):

If you click on `TokenStream` in `fn to_token_stream` you'll notice that it returns `proc_macro2::TokenStream` which is different from `proc_macro::TokenStream` that your function is defined to return. You can read more about this in the [`proc-macro2` docs](https://docs.rs/proc-macro2/latest/proc_macro2/index.html). The way to convert `proc_macro2::TokenStream` to `proc_macro::TokenStream` as recommended in the docs is:

```rust
proc_macro::TokenStream::from(output)
```

In your case, this should work:

```rust
#[proc_macro_attribute]
pub fn log_io(_attr: TokenStream, item: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let item_fn: ItemFn = syn::parse_macro_input!(item);
    proc_macro::TokenStream::from(item_fn.to_token_stream());
}
```

Also, you should import `ToTokens` trait from `quote::ToTokens` (from the `quote` crate) as the `syn` re-export is marked private.